# Dictionary be a Key in a Dictionary Python

Tags: python, hash, dictionary

I want an O(1) method of checking if I have been in a state. The problem is that a state is defined by the position of a few zoombinis on a map. 
Zoombini = {(1,1): 0, (2,2):1, (3,3):3}  {Position: Zoombini ID}
I am using Breadth-First Search and am pushing onto my Queue this dictionary of positions.

```
dirs = [goNorth, goSouth, goWest, goEast] ## List of functions
zoom = {}
boulders = {}
visited = {} ## {(zoom{}): [{0,1,2},{int}]}
             ## {Map: [color, distance] 0 = white, 1 = gray, 2 = black
n = len(abyss)
for i in xrange(n):
    for j in xrange(n):
        if (abyss[i][j] == 'X'):
            boulders[(i,j)] = True
        elif (isInt(abyss[i][j])):
            zoom[(i,j)] = int(abyss[i][j])      ## invariant only 1 zomb can have this position
        elif (abyss[i][j] == '*'):
              exit = (i, j)
sQueue = Queue.Queue()
zombnum = 0
done = False
distance = 0
sQueue.put(zoom)
while not(sQueue.empty()):
    currZomMap = sQueue.get()
    for zom in currZomMap.iterkeys(): ## zoom {(i,j): 0}
        if not(zom == exit):
            z = currZomMap[zom]
            for fx in dirs: ## list of functions that returns resulting coordinate of going in some direction
                newPos = fx(zom)
                newZomMap = currZomMap.copy()
                del(newZomMap[zom]) ## Delete the old position
                newZomMap[newPos] = z ## Insert new Position
                if not(visited.has_key(newZomMap)):
                    sQueue.put(newZomMap)
```

My implementation isn't done but I need a better method of checking if I have already visited a state. I could make a function that creates an integer hash out of the dictionary but I don't think that I'd be able to efficiently. Time is also an issue. How can I go about this optimally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than constructing some fragile custom hash function, I'd probably just use a `frozenset`:

```
>>> Z = {(1,1): 0, (2,2):1, (3,3):3}
>>> hash(Z)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
>>> frozenset(Z.items())
frozenset([((2, 2), 1), ((1, 1), 0), ((3, 3), 3)])
>>> hash(frozenset(Z.items()))
-4860320417062922210
```

The frozenset can be stored in sets and dicts without any problems.  You could also use a tuple built from `Z.items()` but you'd have to ensure it was always stored in a canonical format (say by sorting it first.)

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't allow mutable keys so I ended up creating a function that hashes my dictionary.

edit--

```
def hashthatshit(dictionary):
result = 0
i =0
for key in dictionary.iterkeys():
    x = key[0]
    y = key[1]
    result+=x*10**i+y*10**(i+1)+\
             10**(i+2)*dictionary[key]
    i+=3
return result
```

I used this which is specific to my implementation which is why I originally didn't include it.

Comment: This would be a valid answer if you posted some code about **how** you made this hash function. If you are writing this "answer" to simply negate your original post, then you should delete it, instead

Comment: Are your `x` and `y` values always between 0 and 9? If not, your hash has lots of collisions, such as `{(100,0):0}`, `{(0, 10):0}` and `{(0, 0):1}` which all hash to `100`. For larger dictionaries, hash is also dependent on the order you iterate over the keys of the dictionary, which isn't guaranteed to be stable as you add and remove things.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! You're right, in the end I ended up reversing the dictionary so that the key was the ID and the value was the position because Python automatically sorts dictionaries by key if possible (in the case of integer keys). As for the collisions I ignored it because there were a few guarantees as to what ranges certain numbers will be in (25x25) and (0x4). So collisions won't be to big of an issue.